# Databinding does not work for A-frame tag attributes

Tags: data-binding, angular-cli, aframe, webvr

I'm making a WebVR application with [aframe](/questions/tagged/aframe) and [angular-cli](/questions/tagged/angular-cli). I load some static JSON data from the assets and will bind it to an A-frame element. Here is an example of my JSON data.

```json
{
    "id": 4,
    "image": "",
    "location": "Font",
    "nextScenes": [
        3,
        5
    ],
    "hotspots": [
        {
            "id": "obj1",
            "location": "2325 1305 -2400",
            "rotation": "-5 -50 -5",
            "scale": "150 150 150",
            "headerTitle": "",
            "body": ""
        },
        {
            "id": "obj2",
            "location": "3145 890 -2175",
            "rotation": "-5 -50 -5",
            "scale": "150 150 150",
            "headerTitle": "",
            "body": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

I'll load the `hotspots` in my HTML code with this code:

```html
<a-scene inspector="url: https://aframe.io/releases/0.3.0/aframe-inspector.min.js">
    <a-assets>
        <img id="sky" [src]="currentImageSource" alt="" />
    </a-assets>

    <a-sky src="#sky"></a-sky>

    <!-- problems with code below -->
    <a-entity *ngFor="let spot of currentData.hotspots; let i = index" [id]="spot.id" 
              [position]="spot.location" [rotation]="spot.rotation" [scale]="spot.scale" 
              visible="true" mixin="null" color="pink" 
              text="zOffset:0;value:S;height:100;width:100;align:center"></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

Notice that `currentData` is equal to the JSON code above and `currentImageSource` contains the location of the image.

The problem with code above is that the attributes `position`, `rotation` and `scale` wouldn't bind. In the rendered output are the variables empty but the `ng-reflect-...` attributes aren't empty.

Also if I inspect the code with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>, the object got the `a-entity` tags the default values.

**Update one:** The databinding for the attribute `id` works.

**Update two:** Here you could see the output in my browser:

```html
<app-vrtour _nghost-pub-1="">
  <a-scene class="fullscreen" inspector="" canvas="" keyboard-shortcuts="" screenshot="" vr-mode-ui="" auto-enter-vr="" _ngcontent-pub-1="">
    <a-assets _ngcontent-pub-1="">
      <ewalswebvr-static-assets _ngcontent-pub-1=""><img id="#details" crossorigin="anonymous" scr="/assets/images/details.jpg"></ewalswebvr-static-assets>
      <img id="sky" alt="" src="assets/360images/P5.tif" ng-reflect-src="assets/360images/P5.tif" _ngcontent-pub-1="">
    </a-assets>

    <!--template bindings={"ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object]"}-->
    <!-- The two tags below are the lines that wouldn't bind -->
    <a-entity id="obj1" mixin="null" text="" ng-reflect-id="obj1" ng-reflect-position="2323.81 1305.90 -2400" ng-reflect-rotation="-4.58 -48.7 -5.16" ng-reflect-scale="150 150 150" ng-reflect-visible="true" position="" rotation="" scale="" visible=""
      _ngcontent-pub-1="" ng-reflect-color="#ff0000"></a-entity>
    <a-entity id="obj2" mixin="null" text="" ng-reflect-id="obj2" ng-reflect-position="3145.63 889.46 -2176.50" ng-reflect-rotation="-4.58 -48.7 -5.16" ng-reflect-scale="150 150 150" position="" rotation="" scale="" visible="" _ngcontent-pub-1=""
      ng-reflect-color="#00ff00"></a-entity>

    <a-sky src="#sky" material="" position="" rotation="" scale="" visible="" geometry="" _ngcontent-pub-1=""></a-sky>

    <canvas width="1920" height="930" class="a-canvas a-grab-cursor" style="width: 1920px; height: 930px;" data-aframe-canvas="true"></canvas>
    <div class="a-enter-vr" style="display: none;" aframe-injected=""><button class="a-enter-vr-button" aframe-injected=""></button></div>
    <div class="a-orientation-modal a-hidden" aframe-injected=""><button aframe-injected="">Exit VR</button></div>
    <a-entity aframe-injected="" position="" rotation="" scale="" visible="" camera="" wasd-controls="" look-controls="" data-aframe-inspector="default-camera"></a-entity>
    <a-entity aframe-injected="" position="" rotation="" scale="" visible="" light="" data-aframe-default-light=""></a-entity>
    <a-entity aframe-injected="" position="" rotation="" scale="" visible="" light="" data-aframe-default-light=""></a-entity>
    <a-entity position="" rotation="" scale="" visible="" camera=""></a-entity>
  </a-scene>

</app-vrtour>
```

Could you find the bug in my code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I wonder would the `visible` or `color` binding work? I wonder if Angular overrides `.setAttribute` like A-Frame is as well. But it seems other people have some success: https://github.com/brakmic/Angular2_VR_Starter

Comment: @ngokevin: no the `visible` and `color` binding does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying a workaround, I've found a solution that works. The issue of this code is that it didn't use databinding and I thing it is less performance that databinding but A-frame doesn't support it.

Here you could find the code I've added in my typescript code:

```ts
ngAfterViewInit(): void {

    for (let i: number = this.currentData.hotspots.length; i--;) {

        let spot: any = this.currentData.hotspots[i],
            el: any = document.getElementById(spot.id);

        el.setAttribute("position", spot.location);
        el.setAttribute("rotation", spot.rotation);
        el.setAttribute("scale", spot.scale);
    }
}
```

This code works if I give every `a-entity`-tag an unique ID. The HTML code of my component, is unchanged but it's possible to use this instead.

```html
<a-entity *ngFor="let spot of currentData.hotspots; let i = index" [id]="spot.id"
          text="zOffset:0;value:S;height:100;width:100;align:center"></a-entity>
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason for angular data binding not working is given [here](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#html-attribute-vs-dom-property).

Using Angular one way data binding, you are actually setting the properties of your a-frame entities. However, in real, no such properties exist. These are actually the attributes of those elements. Hence, you area able to manipulate via dom api.

However, using DOM api is not recommended from security perspective. But that is not required either.

To do attributes data binding, you can use similar syntax as follows.

```
<a-entity *ngFor="let spot of currentData.hotspots; let i = index" [id]="spot.id" 
              [attr.position]="spot.location" [attr.rotation]="spot.rotation" [attr.scale]="spot.scale" 
              visible="true" mixin="null" color="pink" 
              text="zOffset:0;value:S;height:100;width:100;align:center"></a-entity>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about what you see in the DOM Inspector. What you are binding is still affecting the scene itself, right? If so, then I think this would answer:

https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/introduction/faq.html#why-is-the-html-dom-not-updating-in-a-frame

> For performance reasons, A-Frame does not update the DOM with component data. Use the debug component to enable component-to-DOM serialization.
>
> By default, for performance reasons, A-Frame does not update the DOM with component data. If we open the browser’s DOM inspector, we will see that many entities will have only the component name visible:
>
> ```html
> <a-entity geometry material position rotation></a-entity>
> ```
>
> The component data is stored internally. Updating the DOM takes CPU time for converting component data, which is stored internally, to strings. However, when we want to see the DOM update for debugging purposes, we can attach the debug component to the scene. Components will check whether the debug component is enabled before trying to serialize to the DOM. Then we will be able to view component data in the DOM:
>
> ```html
> <a-entity geometry="primitive: box" material="color: red" position="1 2 3" 
>           rotation="0 180 0"></a-entity>
> ```
>
> Make sure that this component is not active in production.

Comment: Oke but how can I bind my data to the properties? I need to do that because every hotspot is located on another place. In total I've got 20 till 30 hotstpots on several images.

Comment: If you set `<a-scene debug>`, what does the browser output?

Comment: I don't see differences in the output.

Answer (score 1):

You can get this working in the template (without any `a-entity` setup in the controller class) by using the **[attr.*]** attribute binding syntax, e.g.

```
<a-entity *ngFor="let spot of currentData.hotspots"
              [attr.position]="spot.location" [attr.rotation]="spot.rotation"
              [attr.scale]="spot.scale"
...
```

(And no element ID required.)

REF: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43733797/189518